# Twig error on WebProfiler with Doctrine filter enable

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, symfony-3.3

I have a strange error with Twig and the WebProfiler when I enable a Doctrine filter.

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown 
during the rendering of a template ("Error when rendering "http://community.localhost:8000/
_profiler/e94abf?community_subdomain=community&panel=request" (Status code is 404).")." at 
/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/Resources/views/Profiler/
layout.html.twig line 103
```

This `{{ render(path('_profiler_search_bar', request.query.all)) }}` causes the error.

My doctrine filter allows to add filter constraint on some classes (multi tenant app with dynamic subdomains)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Group\Community;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;

/**
 * Class CommunityAwareFilter
 */
class CommunityAwareFilter extends SQLFilter
{
    /**
     * Gets the SQL query part to add to a query.
     *
     * @param ClassMetadata $targetEntity
     * @param string        $targetTableAlias
     *
     * @return string The constraint SQL if there is available, empty string otherwise.
     */
    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {
        if (!$targetEntity->reflClass->implementsInterface(CommunityAwareInterface::class)) {
            return '';
        }

        return sprintf('%s.community_id = %s', $targetTableAlias, $this->getParameter('communityId')); // <-- error
        // return ''; <-- no error
    }
}
```

I have also extended Symfony Router to add subdomain placeholder automatically in routing.

Do you have any idea what can cause this ?

**UPDATE**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Routing;

use AppBundle\Group\Community\CommunityResolver;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MethodNotAllowedException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router as BaseRouter;

class Router implements RouterInterface
{
    /**
     * @var BaseRouter
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @var RequestStack
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * @var CommunityResolver
     */
    private $communityResolver;

    /**
     * Router constructor.
     *
     * @param BaseRouter        $router
     * @param RequestStack      $request
     * @param CommunityResolver $communityResolver
     */
    public function __construct(BaseRouter $router, RequestStack $request, CommunityResolver $communityResolver)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->communityResolver = $communityResolver;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the request context.
     *
     * @param RequestContext $context The context
     */
    public function setContext(RequestContext $context)
    {
        $this->router->setContext($context);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the request context.
     *
     * @return RequestContext The context
     */
    public function getContext()
    {
        return $this->router->getContext();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the RouteCollection instance associated with this Router.
     *
     * @return RouteCollection A RouteCollection instance
     */
    public function getRouteCollection()
    {
        return $this->router->getRouteCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Tries to match a URL path with a set of routes.
     *
     * If the matcher can not find information, it must throw one of the exceptions documented
     * below.
     *
     * @param string $pathinfo The path info to be parsed (raw format, i.e. not urldecoded)
     *
     * @return array An array of parameters
     *
     * @throws ResourceNotFoundException If the resource could not be found
     * @throws MethodNotAllowedException If the resource was found but the request method is not allowed
     */
    public function match($pathinfo)
    {
        return $this->router->match($pathinfo);
    }

    public function generate($name, $parameters = array(), $referenceType = UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH)
    {
        if (null !== ($community = $this->communityResolver->getCommunity())) {
            $parameters['community_subdomain'] = $community->getSubDomain();
        }

        return $this->router->generate($name, $parameters, $referenceType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, in fact I passed my "tenant" (here my "community") object in the Session like this (in a subscriber onKernelRequest)

```
if (null === ($session = $request->getSession())) {
    $session = new Session();
    $session->start();
    $request->setSession($session);
}
$session->set('community', $community);
```

I changed to store this object in a service and it works. Maybe using the Session to store data is a bad practice.

Answer (score -1):

I think your Symmfony Router override may cause the problem. Can you paste us the code ?